# Change image position on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to switch my image to be on top of the text block when on mobile phone. Current code as below, but it is failing.

```
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 center-block">
        <div class="banner-text col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">
            <h1>Access all your<br/>apps</h1>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg clear-fix">Get Started</a>
        </div>
        <img src="img/banner.png" class="banner-image col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12" />

    </div>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/femiva/mdsvjvLx/) for the code.

Comment: Can you add your css (except for the bootstrap.css)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mdsvjvLx/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot achieve this result with pushing/pulling classes for full width columns (because the sum of the cols adds up to more than the 12).

To achieve the result you want, you could use [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

1) Using the mobile first approach, the column you want to appear on top on the smallest device appears first in the HTML

2) Use the media query to change the order of the columns at breakpoint x (I picked 768px as example):

Example code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container re-order">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 first">
                <h1>On mobile devices this col comes first</h1>             
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 second">
                <h1>On larger screens this gets pulled up</h1>            
          </div>              
      </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .re-order .row {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .re-order .row .first {
    order: 2;
  }
  .re-order .row .second {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@media screen and (max-width ...px)`, along with using a pseudo table in CSS(`display:table;`). Then, in order to change order of your elements, assign `display: table-header-group` for the top table element and `display: table-footer-group` for the bottom element.

Anyway, have a look yourself ;)

---

CSS & HTML:

```css
#example {
  display: table; width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
  #banner-text {
    line-height:180px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    display: table-header-group;
  } /* Will be displayed at the top of the pseudo-table */
  #banner-image {
    line-height:180px;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    display: table-footer-group; 
  } /* Will be displayed at the bottom */
  
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  #banner-text {
    display: table-footer-group;
  } /* Will be displayed at the bottom */
  #banner-image {
    display: table-header-group; 
  } /* Will be displayed at the top */
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
    <div id="banner-text"><h1>TEXTBANNER</h1></div>
    <div id="banner-image"><h1>IMAGEBANNER</h1></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helped!
Cheers,

**Ps.** Try the snippet in fullscreen mode and then try resizing the browser window ;)